# Unable to intall windows 7 with linux mint 17.2 in dual boot. Partition error occuring

Tags: windows, linux-mint

I am running Linux mint 17.2 in my system. I want to install Windows 7 with dual boot but when i tried to install then in partition Windows it shows error " unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition". [My partition window looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSCMf.jpg)

Comment: the error on the photo tells you to "See the setup log files for more information". Please include this information; it will help us AND help you.

Comment: But log files not displaying

Comment: Can anyone solve this without losing data?

Comment: Windows needs to create 1-2 partitions if you're using MBR, and 3 additional partitions if you're using GPT with UEFI. Unfortunately I don't have a definitive answer for you, because all guides specifically say that Windows must come first. What you can look into is how to back up your Linux partition (clonezilla might help), repartition the whole drive so that Windows partition is first, install Windows, then restore the Linux partition after that, and install GRUB.